# Why does Eclipse keep creating a new Run Configuration?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I am writing some scripts in Eclipse 2.7 RC4, using the latest Groovy Eclipse plugin.

Everything works fine except that I have a Run Configuration that I created that passes 2 arguments to the script  but every time I click the Play button to run the project, Eclipse creates a new Groovy Script Run Configuration called "Server (1)".  If I click the Play button again, Eclipse creates another Run Configuration called "Server (2)", etc.

So, every single time I want to run my project, I have to go in and delete the last run configuration it made.

Why does Eclipse do this?  Can't I lock the configuration so that it wont change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Groovy-Eclipse in that it is not recognizing that an existing launch configuration is the "same" as a new one.

Can you get around this by simply re-using the old on explicitly, ie- by clicking on the little arrow to the right of the run button and choosing the old configuration:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I went back to Eclipse 3.6 and the problem doesn't occur.  It appears to be a bug in Eclipse 3.7 Indigo.

Comment: Good to know.  We haven't fully tested Groovy-Eclipse on 3.7 yet.  This is a bug we'll have to sort out before the final release.

Comment: Actually, it worked at first and then I started seeing the problem in 3.6 also.   I worked for long enough to convince me that what I expect to be good behavior is correct.  I think it might be a problem related to the Groovy Eclipse plugin.  One unusual thing about it is that the Groovy Eclipse plugin swaps between 3 different run configuration types: Console, Shell, and Script. That may be a hint as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is quite old but it's still an issue that happens (as it was happening to me today)  I played around with it a little and found that in the 'Run Configurations' window where you can set Arguments/Classpath variables etc there is also a tab named Common.  I found that within this there is an option called "Save as" and if the 'Shared File:' option is selected (pointing to the exported launch configuration) it will keep creating new Run Configs every time you run it. If you instead select the Local File option and Apply the changes, I believe you will stop seeing new run configs saved each time. This worked for me, at least!

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing for Java and Scala test programs I created in Juno version of Eclipse (latest as of Nov 2012).  Very irritating to have to delete all those run configurations explicitly.